# API Calls independent of Actions in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

There are a lot of online tutorials concerning the use of asynchronous APIs from React and Redux. Most of these work on the basis that the API call is made as a result of an action triggered by a user.

What would be the preferred method of making repeated API calls in the background without any user action. I am thinking of the sort of scenario where a database is updated by another application (as an example consider weather station readings) and the Redux store needs to be kept up to date with this data for multiple views to use. As such the data does not 'belong' to any particular view so triggering the API request during componentDidMount is probably not appropriate.

Comment: Solution depends on the way your application receives events. It can be something like timeout, SignalR or socket.io. Pick appropriate library, or implement listeners your way and call actions without user involved.

Comment: An action doesn't have to be triggered by a user. It can be triggered by a window.setInterval() call for example.  You could call window.setInterval() in the componentDidMount() of your top-most component to dispatch an action every 10 seconds, for example. The action would perform the API call, and update the store when it returns.

Comment: @Jeff McCloud This is how I implemented it to start with but felt uncomfortable putting the request in the component when it is not owned by the component. I was hoping to get it out of the view completely. I have now investigated redux-saga and implemented it that way with a saga that runs continuously and keeps the data updated.